# Where to find previous version of wikitudeSDK jar?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, wikitude

i've search for almost a week now and it's hard to find previous version of wikitudesdk.jar because the newest version of it is an aar file. I'm using eclipse for developing android application.  If someone has a previous version of it, mind if you can share it with me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

please reach out to the official Wikitude developer forum for this question including the actual version that you require. Note that after SDK 5.0 there is no official support for Eclipse from Wikitude side